# PHP str word count divide equal parts

Tags: php

i have text file that have **100k** word.php function **str_word_count()**  works and echo me 100k in text file.but i want divide 100k words into 4 equal parts.

```
$data=file_get_contents('100k.txt');
echo $count=str_word_count($data);
```

Comment: what do you mean by four equal parts ? It's like saving again in four seperate files ? or what ?

Comment: eg: we have a whole chicken wants quarter pieces.

Comment: equal number of words but below answer is works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without cutted words:

```
/**
 *  Splits a string with words in equal parts (PHP7)
 *
 *  @since    1.0 DP0
 *  @version  1.0 DP0
 *
 *  @param    string    words   String with words
 *  @param    int       parts   How many parts needed
 *
 *  @return   array             Parts as rec. Array
 */

function split_words_into_parts( string $words, int $parts ) {

      $words_array  = explode( ' ', $words );
      $words_cnt    = count( $words_array );
      $per_part   = max( round( $words_cnt / $parts ), 1 );

      $result     = [];


      /*---  Splitting full array  ---*/

      for( $i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++ )
          $result[] = array_slice( $words_array, $i * $per_part, $per_part );

      return $result;
}


/*---  Usage  ---*/

$v = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';

$result = split_words_into_parts( $v, 4 );

print_r( $result );
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_split()` to split your string into parts. The second argument in str_split is the number of pieces you want to split the string into. The following will count the length of your string, then give you an array containing the string as four array items in the array $pieces.

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque facilisis ultricies efficitur. Integer mattis tincidunt risus id interdum. Integer nulla tellus, imperdiet vitae dui et, sagittis tempus lorem. Maecenas aliquet volutpat purus, sed finibus turpis imperdiet sed. Aliquam erat velit, viverra in nisi vel, euismod porta metus. Vivamus id mi tellus. Fusce sodales dolor dignissim lorem vehicula malesuada. Fusce a tortor in massa viverra blandit. Mauris sit amet sem ligula. Nullam et ullamcorper mi. In porta semper purus a auctor. Cras eget ipsum ut sapien condimentum venenatis vitae ut sem.";

$length = strlen($text);
$pieces = str_split($text, ceil($length/4));
```